# Separate multi-value obs with pairs of values and count

Tags: r

I have a data frame combining single and multi-values obs.

```
 dataset <- c("Apple;Banana;Kiwi",  "orange", "Apple;Banana", "orange" )

 dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
```

My output :

```
           dataset
1 Apple;Banana;Kiwi
2            orange
3      Apple;Banana
4            orange
```

What I want : separate by pairs all the combinaisons of values into 2 columns and count to make a graph

```
from  |to    |weight
Apple |Banana|2
Apple | Kiwi | 1
Banana| Kiwi | 1
orange|NA    |2
```

What I tried :

```
dataset2 <- dataset %>%
  separate_rows(dataset, sep = ";")
```

Comment: @akrun I make a little change we will have 2 orange|NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `combn` on each row and get the frequency

```
stack(table(unlist(lapply(strsplit(dataset$dataset, ";"), 
   function(x) if(length(x) > 1) combn(x, 2, FUN = toString) else x))))[2:1]
```

-output

```
            ind values
1 Apple, Banana      2
2   Apple, Kiwi      1
3  Banana, Kiwi      1
4        orange      2
```

Comment: Great. Very helpfull,  and after I can separate into 2 columns...

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

result <-
  do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(dataset$dataset, ';'), function(x) {
  if(length(x) == 1) return(c(x, NA_character_))
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:(length(x) - 1), function(i) c(x[i], x[i+1])))
}))

as.data.frame(table(paste(result[,1], result[,2]))) %>%
  tidyr::separate(Var1, into = c('from', 'to'), sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(to = ifelse(to == 'NA', NA, to),
         weight = Freq) %>%
  select(-Freq)
#>     from     to weight
#> 1  Apple Banana      2
#> 2 Banana   Kiwi      1
#> 3 orange   <NA>      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pmap(dataset, ~ if (str_detect(.x, ";"))
  {combn(.x %>% str_split(";") %>% unlist, 2, str_c, collapse=";")} else {.x}) %>% 
  map_dfr(data.frame) %>% 
  separate(1, ";", into = c("from", "to"), fill = "right") %>% 
  count(from, to, name = "weight")

#>     from     to weight
#> 1  Apple Banana      2
#> 2  Apple   Kiwi      1
#> 3 Banana   Kiwi      1
#> 4 orange   <NA>      2
```

---

Or without `purrr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataset %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(from = ifelse(str_detect(dataset, ";"), combn(dataset %>% 
         str_split(";") %>% unlist, 2, str_c, collapse=";") %>% list,
         list(dataset))) %>% 
  unnest_longer(from) %>% 
  separate(from, ";", into = c("from", "to"), fill = "right") %>% 
  count(from, to, name = "weight")

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   from   to     weight
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <int>
#> 1 Apple  Banana      2
#> 2 Apple  Kiwi        1
#> 3 Banana Kiwi        1
#> 4 orange <NA>        2
```